# Downloading a pdf generated by a plugin in a webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview, download

I'm creating an app using Universal Android WebView App to access a webpage. This webpage has some downloadable pdfs, only available to logged in users.
The built in Download Manager doesn't work because the pdf is generated by a plugin, and sent in a http response.
I tried to implement the connection myself, tweaking this code http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url

It works and the connection is established just fine, but the file is not downloaded because apparently the Content-Length received is -1. What could be the problem?

Here's the code:

```
public class HttpDownloadUtility extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

/**
 * Downloads a file from a URL
 * @param fileURL HTTP URL of the file to be downloaded
 * @param saveDir path of the directory to save the file
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir) throws IOException {

    String fileName = "";
    URL url = new URL(fileURL);

    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://mywebsite.com"));

    httpConn.connect();

    int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

    // always check HTTP response code first
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

        String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
        String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
        int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

        if (disposition != null) {
            // extracts file name from header field

            int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
            if (index > 0) {
                fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                        disposition.length() - 1);
            }
        } else {
            // extracts file name from URL
            fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                    fileURL.length());
        }

        System.out.println(url.toString());
        System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
        System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
        System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
        System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

        // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

        // opens an output stream to save into file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("File downloaded");



    } else {
        System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
    }
    httpConn.disconnect();

    return fileName;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

    String downloadedFile = "";

    try{
        downloadedFile = downloadFile(url[0], Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return downloadedFile;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found that the DownloadManager can be configured with the cookies I needed. Here's the code in case anyone needs it (I don't use the class I mentioned in the question anymore).

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "mypdf.pdf");
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(1);
                request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url));
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);
```